# How can I customize the default workflow email templates in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I know how to customize an *instance* of an email template using SharePoint Designer 2010, but when there are conceivably dozons of instances of an approval process it can be tedious to adjust each email template instance in turn.

Is there a way to customize the core templates upon which all these process emails are based? (so I only need to customize the email templace *once*)

Ideally I am looking for a code-free solution, but I'm willing to hear from both camps on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is not possible unless you are using SharePoint Designer or a custom coded solution.